# Float is not converting to integer pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, floating-point, integer

I used this code to convert my float numbers into an integer, however, it does not work. Here are all step I gone through so far:

```
Step 1: I converted timestamp1 and timestamp2 to datetime in order subtract and get days:

a=pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp1'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
b=pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp2'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
df['delta'] = (b-a).dt.days

Step 2: Converted the strings into integers as the day:
df['delta'] = pd.to_datetime(df['delta'], format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='coerce')
df['delta'] = df['delta'].dt.day

Step 3: I am trying to convert floats into integers.

categorical_feature_mask = df.dtypes==object
categorical_cols = df.columns[categorical_feature_mask].tolist()

        from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
        le = LabelEncoder()
        df[categorical_cols] = df[categorical_cols].apply(lambda col: le.fit_transform(col)) 
df[categorical_cols].head(10)


However, it throws an error TypeError: ('argument must be a string or number', 'occurred at index col1')
```

Comment: your column is of type character not float, and what is the meaning of comparing variable with itself  x == x will always evaluate to True.

Comment: @adnanmuttaleb thank you. could you please help with the fix?

Answer (score 0):

To convert a float column to an integer with float columns having NaN values two things you can do:

1. Convert to naive int and change NaN values to an arbitrary value such as this:

   `df[col].fillna(0).astype("int32")`
2. If you want to conserve NaN values use this:

   `df[col].astype("Int32")`

Note the difference with the capital "I". For further information on this implementation made by Pandas just look at this: [Nullable integer data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html).

Why do you need to do that ? Because by default Pandas considers that when your column has at least on `NaN` value, the column is a Float, because this is how [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/misc.html) behaves.

The same thing happen with strings, if you have at least one string value in your column, the whole column would be labeled as `object` for Pandas, so this is why your first attempt failed.

Comment: it throws an error "invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''"

Comment: Do you have some strings in your column ? Is it possible to have a sample ? Also because you edited your question, my answer appears irrelevant, which one of your implementations are you really using ?
If your column is filled by float values in a string representation, you first need to convert the column as a float and then you can convert it into an integer column.

Answer (score 0):

> You can convert columns from float to int using this. Use errors='ignore' if the data contains null values

```
df[column_name] =  df[column_name].astype("Int64", errors="ignore")
```