# Why can I not use Python Pandas int types (like Int8Dtype) in statsmodels.formula.api regressions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, statsmodels

Regressions that will work with numpy int types and even with bool types will in case of pandas int types fail with `TypeError: data type not understood`

**Sample code**

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"y": [0.02, 0.011, 0.01, 0.06, 0.12, 0.015],
                   "x": [False, False, False, True, True, False]
                   })
df["x2"] = df["x"].astype('int8')
df["x3"] = df["x"].astype('Int8')
print(df)
print([df[col].dtype for col in df.columns])
model = smf.logit(formula="y ~ x", data=df)     #This works.
print(model.fit().summary())
model = smf.logit(formula="y ~ x2", data=df)    #This works too.
print(model.fit().summary())
model = smf.logit(formula="y ~ x3", data=df)    #This does not work.
print(model.fit().summary())
```

**Note:** Never mind the values, sample sizes and goodness in these regressione, I know they are not useful. They are meant as a minimal reproducible example.

**Sample output**

```
$ python3 regtest.py 
       y      x  x2  x3
0  0.020  False   0   0
1  0.011  False   0   0
2  0.010  False   0   0
3  0.060   True   1   1
4  0.120   True   1   1
5  0.015  False   0   0
[dtype('float64'), dtype('bool'), dtype('int8'), Int8Dtype()]
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.057534
         Iterations 8
/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/discrete/discrete_model.py:3390: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  return 1 - self.llf/self.llnull
                           Logit Regression Results                           
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   No. Observations:                    6
Model:                          Logit   Df Residuals:                        4
Method:                           MLE   Df Model:                            1
Date:                Wed, 30 Oct 2019   Pseudo R-squ.:                     inf
Time:                        20:01:22   Log-Likelihood:               -0.34520
converged:                       True   LL-Null:                        0.0000
Covariance Type:            nonrobust   LLR p-value:                     1.000
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept     -4.2546      4.256     -1.000      0.317     -12.596       4.086
x[T.True]      1.9410      4.921      0.394      0.693      -7.704      11.586
==============================================================================
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.057534
         Iterations 8
/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/discrete/discrete_model.py:3390: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  return 1 - self.llf/self.llnull
                           Logit Regression Results                           
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   No. Observations:                    6
Model:                          Logit   Df Residuals:                        4
Method:                           MLE   Df Model:                            1
Date:                Wed, 30 Oct 2019   Pseudo R-squ.:                     inf
Time:                        20:01:22   Log-Likelihood:               -0.34520
converged:                       True   LL-Null:                        0.0000
Covariance Type:            nonrobust   LLR p-value:                     1.000
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept     -4.2546      4.256     -1.000      0.317     -12.596       4.086
x2             1.9410      4.921      0.394      0.693      -7.704      11.586
==============================================================================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "regtest.py", line 16, in <module>
    model = smf.logit(formula="y ~ x3", data=df)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py", line 159, in from_formula
    missing=missing)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/formula/formulatools.py", line 65, in handle_formula_data
    NA_action=na_action)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/patsy/highlevel.py", line 310, in dmatrices
    NA_action, return_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/patsy/highlevel.py", line 165, in _do_highlevel_design
    NA_action)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/patsy/highlevel.py", line 70, in _try_incr_builders
    NA_action)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/patsy/build.py", line 696, in design_matrix_builders
    NA_action)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/patsy/build.py", line 448, in _examine_factor_types
    done = cat_sniffers[factor].sniff(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/patsy/categorical.py", line 198, in sniff
    if hasattr(data, "dtype") and safe_issubdtype(data.dtype, np.bool_):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/patsy/util.py", line 710, in safe_issubdtype
    return np.issubdtype(dt1, dt2)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numerictypes.py", line 393, in issubdtype
    arg1 = dtype(arg1).type
TypeError: data type not understood
```

**Why would I want this?** In order to save memory, I may want to convert data that contains `NaN`s into integer types while conserving the `NaN`s. There is a [question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57264509/1735215); the answer recommends `df[col].astype("Int32")` as the easiest solution. Float data types can be very memory consuming if I have many observations, so it would be desirable to use small integer types instead. Of course, I could remove the `NaN`s by hand and then use numpy types, but this is a lot of hassle, a potential source of errors and, I guess, also not very pythonic.

**Software** Linux kernel 5.3.7, Python 3.7.4, Pandas 0.25.2, Statsmodels 0.10.1

Comment: These `nan` compatible integer dtypes are *relatively* new to pandas, and there is still a warning the the API is not stable, so likely, libraries that rely on / work with pandas won't entirely incorporate them for some time. In any case, statsmodels is built on top of numpy, not pandas.

Comment: the computation will have to be in float64 to get reasonable numerical precision, so any int dtype will not help for memory reduction in the model fit.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks, this is a valuable hint. I was not aware of that. The problem with numpy seems to be that `nan` implies float.

Comment: @Josef Do you mean on the level of `statsmodels.formula.api.logit` or do you mean for logit regressions in general? The latter is not true; imagine the variable in question to be a dummy variable. I reduced the example to highlight the issue that I am asking about (which is the failure of `statsmodels.formula.api` to work with pandas int types). This does not change if you include further explanatory variables. As mentioned in the OP, I am aware of the fact that regressions should not be done with only a dummy as explaining variable.

Comment: patsy builds a design matrix, `exog`, from the formula and original data. That design matrix includes the dummy variables and should be float64 for the computation. (It might work with lower precision numerical types in the fit, but that has not been verified.)

Comment: Having only dummy variables as regressors is not a problem. The simplest case is when we compare means across two samples using a regression model like OLS, Logit or GLM.